# Центрирование карусели фотографий

Tags: jquery

Сделал вертикальную карусель фотографий. 
Выводим в div.listPhoto миниатюры фоток. Div фиксированной высоты. Т.е. когда много - появляется полоса прокрутки. Всё нормально.

```
<div class="listPhoto">
    <a href="..." id="1"><img src="..."></a>
    ...
    <a href="..." id="n"><img src="..."></a>
</div>
```

Div в который выводится большая фотка (работает на подмене атрибута src при клике на миниатюрку):

```
<div class="bigPhoto">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Как сделать, что бы при клике на ссылку в диве listPhoto, блок с фотками прокручивался а эта ссылка-миниатюрка оказывалась выравненна вертикально по центру в родительском блоке listPhoto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/vparV/2/). Работает, но надо учитывать погрешности. Например, если в ваших превьюшках есть какие-либо отступы (padding, margin)

```
var thumbs = $('.listPhoto img');
var bigImg = $('.bigPhoto img');
var thumbHalfHeight = $('.listPhoto').height() / 2;
thumbs.click(function(){
    bigImg.attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    var curScroll = $('.listPhoto').scrollTop();
    var topSpaceHeight = Math.ceil(thumbHalfHeight - $(this).height() / 2);
    var curImgPos = $(this).position().top.toFixed();
    var scrollingTo = curScroll - (topSpaceHeight - curImgPos);
    $('.listPhoto').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollingTo
    });
});
```